# Not able to find user_config.jam while installing boost libraries

Tags: boost, boost-build

I'm trying to compile a Kinect v2 point cloud example created by someone else, on windows 8.1. This Visual studio example has a dependency on a library called

> libboost_mpi-vc120-mt-gd-1_57.lib

I googled for a long time but did not find a downloadable version of this pre-compiled library (there are downloadable versions of pre-compiled boost libraries, but they don't contain binaries for the boost MPI library), so I decided to build one. Every time I try to build boost library it says

```
"warning: skipping optional Message Passing Interface (MPI) library.
note: to enable MPI support, add "using mpi ;" to user-config.jam."
```

Every forum as well as the boost documentation I checked says that user-config.jam needs to be modified and adding `'using mpi;'` to it compiles the libs for mpi.

However I'm not able to find a file called user-config.jam anywhere the boost folder (except one site-config.jam and one user-config.jam in `pathto\boost_1_57_0\tools\build\example\`).

All forums say there should be a user-config.jam in `pathto\boost_1_57_0\tools\build\` but I did not find any. So I created my own user-config.jam in that location and added `'using mpi;'` to that file but it still doesn't compile the mpi libs. I also tried putting one user-config.jam in `pathto\boost_1_57_0` and installing again from the `pathto\boost_1_57_0` but I get the same result (i.e. no MPI binaries anywhere).

The way I'm building is as mentioned on the official documentation [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/bbv2/installation.html). Even though the documentation says boost cannot build without user-config.jam, I was actually able to build it from the pathto\boost_1_57_0 folder; so I'm stumped as to what's going on.

Is there anything I'm missing. All this is just because the VStudio project has a dependency on that one lib file. And the one lib file I need belongs to the one library boost isn't building :(. If anyone has it (libboost_mpi-vc120-mt-gd-1_57.lib) and can attach it that'll be great as well :). Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to place the `user-config.jam` file in your `HOME` directory, just specify its location while calling `b2`:

```
$ ./b2 --user-config=/path/to/user-config.jam ...
```

Answer (score 4):

> However I'm not able to find a file called user-config.jam anywhere
>   the boost folder (except one site-config.jam and one user-config.jam
>   in pathto\boost_1_57_0\tools\build\example).

The directory you're looking for is `pathto\boost_1_57_0\tools\build\src`.

In other words, create and edit the following file:

`pathto\boost_1_57_0\tools\build\src\user-config.jam`.

You can start off from the example file if you want `pathto\boost_1_57_0\tools\build\example\user-config.jam`, by copying it to the aforementioned location.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick for me! I did not want to install the user-config.jam file into my home directory.

Answer (score 1):

The official [documentation](https://www.bfgroup.xyz/b2/manual/release/index.html#bbv2.overview.configuration) explains where you can place the `user-config.jam` file. One possible location is your `HOME` directory. For which the exact location depends on your OS and particular configuration.

Comment: link is dead (404) at the moment

Comment: specific version links like this seem to still work : https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/bbv2/overview.html

Comment: @PeterT we moved to a new b2 website recently and direct link no longer work. I updated the link to reflect the new location.